# Verilog array syntax

Tags: verilog

I'm new to Verilog, and am having a lot of trouble with it. For example, I want to have an array with eight cells, each of which is 8 bits wide. The following doesn't work:

```
reg [7:0] transitionTable [0:7];
assign transitionTable[0] = 10;
```

neither does just doing `transitionTable[0] = 10;` or `transitionTable[0] = 8'h10;` Any ideas?

(In case it is not obvious and relevant: I want to make a finite state machine, and specify the state transitions in an array, since that seems easier than a massive case switch.)

Comment: Just FYI: doing it in a massive case switch is easier and standard practice. By which, I mean, you can do it this way, but on an interview for a job you'll need to provide the switch-case way.

Comment: @aqua: thanks, I guess I'll go the switch way then.

Comment: Unless you have a boss, you're the designer with the final say. You can do it however _you_ want to. But in my experience (and the advice I've received) doing it with switch statements is easier (easier to get it right the first time) and it is 100% accepted.

Comment: this would be a perfect question for this Area 51 proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20632/programmable-logic-and-fpga-design?referrer=YmxhQ2OJUo-FAaI1gMp5oQ2 consider supporting it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `assign` you should declare the array as a `wire` instead of a`reg`.

Comment: Update: confirmed in simulation.

Answer (score 2):

Since your goal is to design an FSM, there is no need to store the state values in an array. This is typically done using Verilog `parameter`'s, a `state` register and a `next_state` with a `case/endcase` statement.

The following paper shows a complete example: [FSM Fundamentals](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsICU2002_FSMFundamentals.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If this is targeted towards synthesis:

A little beyond what was answered above, there are standard FSM coding styles that you should adhere to so the tools can perform better optimization. As described in the Cummings paper, one-hot is usually best for FPGA devices and in fact ISE(with default settings) will ignore your encoding and implement whatever it thinks will best utilize the resources on the device. This almost invariably results in a one-hot encoded FSM regardless of the state encoding you chose, provided it recognizes your FSM.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so to answer your question, let's dig a little deeper into Verilog syntax.

First of all, to specify a range of bits, either do `[MSB:LSB]` or `[LSB:MSB]`. The standard is `MSB:LSB` but it is really up to you here, but try to be consistent.

Next, in array instantiation we have:

`reg WIDTH reg_name NUMBER;`

where `WIDTH` is the "size" of each element and `NUMBER` is the number of elements in the array.

So, you first want to do:

`reg [7:0] transitionTable [7:0];`

Then, to assign particular bytes (8 bits = 1 byte), do:

```
initial begin
    transitionTable[0] = 8'h10;
end
```

A good book to learn Verilog from is *FPGA Prototyping By Verilog Examples* by Pong P. Chu.

Comment: Using this type of always block when there is nothing to be sensitive to is a little awkward. I think the original assign is clearer.

Comment: Actually, this answer won't even work. As there is no sensitivity list inferred, the always block will never trigger and transitionTable[0] will stay at x. I wonder why this was marked as OK :-)