# How to make an array in 'verilog' (code inside)

Tags: arrays, verilog, iverilog

I want to make an array called 'a' and fill it with any binary numbers

and It's 1-D array
my code must do as sw in mips (store word)
'm' the value that I want to store it in 's'

Thank you,

```
module ALU(m,s,control,out,zeroflag,array);

input [31:0] m,s;
input [7:0] control;
output reg [31:0] out;
output reg zeroflag;
reg a [0:2]; // this is the array

a[2] = 4'b0000; // filled it..
a[1] = 4'b1001;
a[0] = 4'b0110;

always @(m,s,control,out,zeroflag,array)
begin
case(control)
8'h2B :  if(s==8'h0) a[0] = m;
         out = a[0];
  else if(s==8'h1) a[1] = m;
         out = a[1];
  else             a[2] = m;
         out = a[2];

endcase
end

always @(out)
begin
if(out==0)
zeroflag <= 1;
else
zeroflag <= 0;
end
endmodule
```

//////////////////////////////////////////

```
module test;
reg [31:0] m,s;
reg [7:0] control;
wire [31:0] outpt;
wire zeroflag;

ALU rtypeoperations(m,s,control,outpt,zeroflag);
initial
begin
m=32'b0000; s=8'h0; control=8'h2B; //stores m value in array[0] if s=8'h0, stores m value in array[1] if s=8'h1, stores m value in array[2] if s=8'h2,
end

initial
begin
$monitor("At time = %0t ,result = %b, zero flag = %b ",$time ,outpt,zeroflag);
end
endmodule
```

Comment: What is happening instead of what you expected? Does [this question on arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846898/verilog-array-syntax) give you the solution?

Comment: You need a clock to 'store word'

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of problems in your code. Does this even compile?

First, your operations for filling the array needs to be inside an `initial` block.

```
initial begin
  a[2] = 4'b0000; // filled it..
  a[1] = 4'b1001;
  a[0] = 4'b0110;
end
```

Please note that `initial` blocks are allowed for FPGA rtl (FPGAs can have power on initial values for registers) and for behavioural (testbench) code, but not for ASICs.

Second, your `always @(m,s,control,out,zeroflag,array)` contains outputs in the sensitivity list. It should only be inputs.

Third -- you need some clocks in your code. Right now everything is combinational logic the way it's written.

Finally, learn to indent your code properly. Here's one suggestion for coding guidelines: https://github.com/NetFPGA/netfpga/wiki/VerilogCodingGuidelines